# Syntax error with an extend in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, extend

This is my main.

```
package oleg;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class main_class {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int length,shetach,num;

        zura[] z1 = new zura[5];    

        for(int i=0;i<z1.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter 1,2,or 3");
            Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);
            num = s1.nextInt();
            switch (num) {
                case 1:

                    z1[i] = new ribua();
                System.out.println("Enter length");
                length=s1.nextInt();
                z1[i].set_info();
                z1[i].shetach(length);
                System.out.println(shetach);    ////// here is the error

                break;

                default:
               System.out.println("error 3");
                   break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my first class from which I inherit.

```
package oleg;

public class zura {

    public int shetach(int shetach)
    {
        return shetach;
    }

    public void heikef()
    {

    }

    public void set_info()
    {

    }
}
```

This is my second class that extands the zura class

```
package oleg;

public class ribua extends zura {

    int length;

    public int shetach(int shetach)
    {
        shetach=length*length;
        return shetach;
    }

    public void set_info(int length)
    {
        this.length=length;
    }
```

My problem is in the `main` class in the row `System.out.println(shetach);`
How am I printing the shetach?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: And paste the complete and exact error message. It says what the problem is, and where. Hiding it from us is counter-productive.

Comment: I assume it's caused by the variable shetach not having been initialized. Your shetach function returns an int, but you never store it in the shetach variable. So probably just change `z1[i].shetach(length);` to `shetatch = z1[i].shetach(length);`. But it would help if you explained better and made less of a mess :)

Comment: um, the variable shetach doesn't exist in the scope where you print it.

Comment: I don't understand why this particular post is so hard to edit. The spacing will simply not line up. Someone else can give it a go.

Comment: thank you @DaniëlKnippers you are a good man ,you helped me  alot

Comment: the answer was to write shetatch = z1[i].shetach(length);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a variable to a method it is *copied*.  This means if you set that variable in the method it has no effect on the caller. i.e. it doesn't initialise the callers copy of the variable.  You need to change your code to look like this.

```
shetatch = z1[i].shetach(length);
```

The variable `shetatch` inside the method has the same name. but otherwise nothing in common.

Answer (score 2):

It says that the local variable shetach may not have been initialized.
You have to initialize all your local variables. That's why its giving error.